# python openpyxl max_row counts all the rows instead of counting non-empty rows

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using a excel sheet where it has 999 in total of rows and in which 20 rows are data filled rows and others are empty.

so when i print max_rows it gives me 999 numbers instead of 20 number! i am following this tutorial - [openpyxl tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/)

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
s = wb.active
print(s.max_row)
```

Comment: dont down vote unless you dont write why you doing so, so i can correct my quest.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to count them yourself if you want to use openpyxl

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active
count = 0
for row in ws:
    if any(cell.value is not None for cell in row):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Or

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active
print(len(
    [row for row in ws if any(cell.value is not None for cell in row)]
))
```

Explanation

If a cell doesn't have any value in an xlsx it is `None` when you get its value. The check `cell.value is None for cell in row` will only trigger if a row doesn't have any data at all. You could easily swap `all` for `any` to not count rows with any empty fields.

Comment: better to use `cell.value is None` instead of `cell.value == None` because we shouldn't compare None with the equality operators

Answer (score 2):

That is expected. As per the docs `max_row` returns

> The maximum row index containing data (1-based)

i.e. the maximum row index, not number of rows with data. If you have data just on e.g. row 100 you will get 100, not 1

Comment: thanks for clearing the confusion so is there something in openpyxl which i can use to know number of rows or column filled with data? I need to know how many fields are complete so i can get their count and iterate to insert in database, i can do so using pandas but i am restricted to use so.

Comment: you can iterate over cells in a column and check how many are not empty

Comment: i found a new package xlrd. it seems like working as expected

Comment: feel free to use it if suits your needs better :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to use

```
if not all([  (cell.value == None or cell.value =='') for cell in row]):
```

to not count blank cells containing formatting.  Otherwise, for .xlsx files, I would get a count of around 1048535.